# Undefined error when setting CSS values with express data

Tags: css, node.js, express, mongoose

I am running into a bit of an issue, I have a user object which I have an array where a user can set their own styling options when I attempt to load the page where this styling is needed I get a following error

**Error**

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'primaryColor' of undefined`

**Code**

HTML: `<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:<%=user.branding.primaryColor%>;">`

Route:

```
 router.get("/:username", function (req, res) {
        User.find({ username: req.params.username}, function (err, foundUser) {
            if(empty(foundUser)){
                res.render("error", {err:"the user " +req.params.username + " does not exist "})
            } else {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Oh no error: ", err)
                }
                Link.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function (err, foundLinks) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Oh no error 2: ", err);
                    }
                    res.render('dashboard/preview', {
                        user: foundUser,
                        links: foundLinks,
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

foundUser:

```
[
   {
    links: { link: [] },
    settings: { accountIsAccountActive: true, darkMode: false },
    branding: {
       primaryColor: '#D46975',
       secondaryColor: '#9646C8',
       image: 'https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/default-image-png-1.png',
       linkRadius: '15px',
       linkColor: '#FFFFFF'
    },
     _id: 5eef79490e264c,
     firstname: 'testy',
     lastname: 'test',
     username: 'test',
     __v: 0
  }
]
```

I am starting to feel like this may not be possible, thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: What is foundUser and what is it like?

Comment: Hey, foundUser is the user modal from the db and is generally returned as 

`[
   {
    links: { link: [] },
    settings: { accountIsAccountActive: true, darkMode: false },
    branding: {
       primaryColor: '#D46975',
       secondaryColor: '#9646C8',
       image: 'https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/default-image-png-1.png',
       linkRadius: '15px',
       linkColor: '#FFFFFF'
    },
     _id: 5eef79490e264c,
     firstname: 'testy',
     lastname: 'test',
     username: 'test',
     __v: 0
  }
]`

sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add code like that in your comment. That way it's easier to read.

Comment: Added the foundUser object to the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foundUser is an array. In your HTML code, you need to use

```
user[0].branding.primaryColor
```

**Or**
change mongo query from

```
User.find()
```

to

```
User.findOne()
```

**Or**
Assign foundUser[0] to user.

```
res.render('dashboard/preview', {
    user: foundUser[0],
    links: foundLinks,
});
```